# Can I associate a GitHub gist with an organization?

Tags: github, version-control

My team has a GitHub organization account. A lot of the work I do results in one-off scripts that we want to be able to have on our organization page but that aren't big enough projects to justify their own repository.

Is there any way to associate [Gists](http://www.sitepoint.com/github-gist-is-pastie-on-steroids/) with GitHub organization accounts?

If not, what's the best way to 'check-in' or associate smaller scripts into GitHub's shared organizational repository?

Comment: Oh how I wish this was possible... Ideally gists could be submitted to an organization by approval, pretty much like a pull request.

Comment: see [this discussion about organization gist in community/community](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/7923 "Organization gists · Discussion #7923 · community/community")

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Found the answer on [Github's support site](http://support.github.com/discussions/organization-issues/307-organization-gist-editing) ([now archived here](http://web.archive.org/web/20101028021406/http://support.github.com/discussions/organization-issues/307-organization-gist-editing)):

The answer, as of October 2010, is No.

> It's planned but we don't have a
>   timeframe available -- sorry about
>   that.

Comment: Apparently as of June 2020, the answer is still no. There's no mention of gists on GitHub's [About organizations](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/about-organizations) page. And gistboxapp.com doesn't exist any more.

Answer (score 27):

So here's a crazy hack. If you create a new github account and make a bunch of gists, you can then convert that account into an Organization and the gists stay associated with the new Organization.

Big caveat: you won't be able to create any new gists for that Organization. But you can edit existing ones. :-\

Comment: Haha, that is a bizarre hack. Why doesn't github just let us add more?

Answer (score 1):

For the time being, I think it would be best to start a new organization repository and put all your gists in there. Use the repository interface on Github [to manage your gists](https://help.github.com/categories/81/articles).

If you want the gists to be publicly available, create a public repository. If you want them to be internal, create a private repository and limit the audience to your organization's users. As bonus perks, you can also add media and reference them from the gists. I think one could also argue that it's easier to navigate a Git repo than a user's list of gists.

So, seems a gist behaves a lot like, well... a Git file!

Comment: The big difference is that a private gist's url can be shared with anyone, and they can see the content, not so much for private repositories. For me, private gists really work well for company-wide shell scripts that you can pipe directly to bash, but right now, they have to be hosted by a person, unfortunately.

Comment: important thing to mention: private repositories are always paid, while private gists are as free as open stuff on Github.